Not sure if these mineral flakes (?) are normal and what the "right" way to burn in a new oven is
I bought a new oven (Bosch). The guy who came to install checked everything was working and then set it up to run for 30 mins on the highest setting. There was nothing in the oven, no package material or the like. He told me to wipe the surfaces down once it had cooled off - and he said not to clean or wipe anything before since it had to be "burned in" first. Then he left.
Later, after I was able to check the manual, I found out it should have been the opposite of what that guy told me. To first wipe down all even surfaces with a damp cloth and THEN run the oven for 1 hour at high temperature. Well...too late for that since installation guy had already started things...is that going to be a problem that I didn't wipe it down first? That's what it says in the manual...
I then went to wipe down the surfaces...and found some kind of mineral wool flakes inside the oven...yellowish with black spots in it. That definitely wasn't there before.
Now I'm worried about two things: first off, what are these flakes? Where did they come from? I read that mineral wool is good for insulation, but highly dangerous when breathed in or - I guess in the case of an oven - eaten if it were to fall into food? And second, is it dangerous that I did not wipe the surfaces down with a wet cloth before burning it in? Could that have burned in some residue left over from the production that I was meant to clean off with the cloth?
It's the first new oven I bought... so I'm hoping someone with experience can help.

Relax, wipe it down as instructed. This will remove any burned material and burn in as directed in the manual. Unless it was 1/2 full of insulation or plastic, I think you are safe.
